# Arial Narrow font changed to Myriad Pro when Adobe form is generated

Tags: abap, adobe-form

A custom program creates a BOM report(an Adobe form) using selection screen parameters and download report on Presentation server.

The report is made in ADOBE FORMS where the font is set as Arial Narrow for all fields in Palettes. However, when the form is downloaded font changes to Myriad Pro. Acrobat Reader is used as a default program to generate PDFs. How can Arial Narrow be printed in output.

Comment: Is Arial presented in your system?

Answer (score 0):

I would check SAP Note [2367603](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2367603) - *Arial font missing in PDF output*.  This was released on September 20th, 2016. Could be a good starting point for you.